# Click through the image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a image border (its on hexagon map so border must be image) that shows on hover on each hex. And now i want to use jQuery .click() function on some hexes but I can't click on the hex through the hover image. Is there any way to solve it?

Thank you very much.

PS: The hover image looks like this: 
http://perludus.com/examples/hexmap/hex-highlight.png
(border and the rest is transparent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can compare coordinates. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/AsWb9/) I've made.

Comment: Nice solution, but If you see the code maybe you devise some better solution: http://www.dark-project.cz/wesnoth/map-view/1

Comment: @Kryštof, here i've made [example](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/3FRWD/2/) using your code and my getHover function

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Handle the `click` event on the overlay element itself, or
- Make the overlay element a descendant of the hex it's currently lying over, so the `click` event will bubble from the overlay up to the hex element.

Seeing some of your code would allow for a more precise answer.

Comment: Thank you for answer. First method is out of the question, because I have several different .click events. Second is better but I have big hex map so if I use this solution I must include the hover image to the web many times...